# UI Kitten - List component - How to get selected item

Tags: react-native, user-interface, react-native-flatlist, react-native-ui-kitten

I am building React-Native CLI app using the UI Kitten UI kit. In my render I have the below list.

```
  <List
    style={styles.listContainer}
    data={providerTypes}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.Id.toString()}
  />
```

I have these methods for the list item and onPress events.

```
 const renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
    <ListItem
      title={`${item.ServiceCategory}`}
      description={`${item.ServiceType} `}
      accessoryRight={renderItemIcon}
      onPress={(item) => typeSelected(item)}
    />
  );
  const typeSelected = (item) => {
    console.log('item: ', item);
    console.log('item.Id: ', item.Id);
    alert('You touched list item: ', item.Id);
  };
```

When the typeSelected method is fired, item.Id is null, but item is one giant object with so much data, but I cannot find my item data anywhere in there?

I am very new to Kitten library and I dont know TypeScript much at all. I am also not using TypeScript in  RN app, so I'm struggling to figure out how to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are getting the even instead of the item

when you do

```
onPress={(item) => typeSelected(item)}
```

The item refers to the event and not the item in the index

you have to change it to

```
onPress={() => typeSelected(item)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try

```
onChangeText={item => typeSelected(item)}
```

or

```
onChange={item => typeSelected(item)}
```

method because ListItem from react-native-ui-kitten uses props from react-native Flatlist component